# Application crash on fetching the operationCount of the OperationQueue

Tags: ios, swift, concurrency, nsoperationqueue, nsoperation

Some times I receive crash when I try to access `.operationCount` of the `OperationQueue`.

Example of the issue.

`parallelOperationQueue` is computed variable that is declared in the file.

```
private var parallelOperationQueue: OperationQueue = {
        let queue = OperationQueue()
        queue.qualityOfService = .background
        return queue
}()
```

Than place where crash occurs :

```
private func parallelOperations(for tokens: [TokenObject]) {
        guard parallelOperationQueue.operationCount == 0, !tokens.isEmpty else {
            return
        }
}
```

Additionally function `parallelOperations` is called in async block.

```
 DispatchQueue.main.async {

 }
```

App crash log.

```
Crashed: com.apple.main-thread
0  _                          0x100967ba0 specialized TokensViewModel.parallelOperations(for : [TokenObject]) -> () (TokensViewModel.swift:73)
1  _                          0x100967dac specialized TokensViewModel.(runOperations() -> ()).(closure #1).(closure #1) (TokensViewModel.swift:151)
2  _                          0x1009681b0 partial apply for TokensViewModel.(runOperations() -> ()).(closure #1).(closure #1) + 4300276144
3  _                          0x10098fe90 thunk (FloatLabelTextField.swift)
4  libdispatch.dylib              0x184d9cb24 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 24
5  libdispatch.dylib              0x184d9cae4 _dispatch_client_callout + 16
6  libdispatch.dylib              0x184da96e0 _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF$VARIANT$mp + 1012
7  CoreFoundation                 0x185453070 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__ + 12
8  CoreFoundation                 0x185450bc8 __CFRunLoopRun + 2272
9  CoreFoundation                 0x185370da8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 552
10 GraphicsServices               0x187353020 GSEventRunModal + 100
11 UIKit                          0x18f35178c UIApplicationMain + 236
12 _                              0x100931208 main (DepositCoordinator.swift:8)
13 libdyld.dylib                  0x184e01fc0 start + 4
```

Comment: Is there any call stack?

Comment: @Vyacheslav I add crash log.